# How to repair flaked plaster surface

Tags: repair, drywall, walls, hole, diy-vs-pro

[image: Flaking][image: Cracked wall]

I recently moved and noticed this crack on the wall. When I tapped it lightly with a blunt knife it broke off. I've never plastered before but I assume I will need to re-plaster this section. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How thick is the layer that's breaking off?

Comment: The layer breaking off seems to be very thin less than 0.1cm

Comment: Looks like flaking paint to me, not plaster.

Comment: I had a builder in the other day for another reason and when he did have a look at the wall he mentioned it was a poor plaster job in that section but stated it was easy to repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd tap the rest of the wall and see really how much you need to repair. From the photo it looks as though you will have another inch or two upwards and at least another inch going down. This is a really easy fix though. You can get a tub of mud (plaster patch) at any home improvement, hardware or even your local department store and even large grocery stores carry it. Get a putty knife and it would help if you got a 6" or 8" drywall knife to make a smoother coat (saves sanding time). Then lookup how to patch drywall and/or drywall finishing on YouTube. There's a ton of great short videos that will show you better than we can tell you.

Comment: Yep. Just know that sanding should be an extremely minor part of the job. Too many folks think you need to sand the wall into shape after taping/patching. Not so. 99% of the job is done with the knife, and more thin applications are better than fewer heavy ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I think will do this for the plaster patch should i look to get a pre mixed solution?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like poorly-adhering paint to me, possibly on top of a crack in the plaster. You'll need to remove all the loose paint you can find. Then, feather the sharp edges of paint with a thin layer of plaster, prime, and paint the wall.